# how can i set operators priority in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim equation As String
Dim numbers() As String
Dim operators As New List(Of String)
Dim result As Double
Dim rx As New Regex("(\+|\-|\*)+")
Dim matches As MatchCollection

equation = TextBox1.Text
numbers = equation.Split(New String() {"+"c, "-"c, "*"c}, StringSplitOptions.None)
matches = rx.Matches(equation)

Dim m1 As Match

For Each m1 In matches
    operators.Add(m1.Value)
Next

result = CInt(numbers(0))
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To numbers.GetUpperBound(0)
    Select Case operators(i - 1)
        Case "*"
            result *= CDec(numbers(i))
        Case "+"
            result += CDec(numbers(i))
        Case "-"
            result -= CDec(numbers(i))
        Case " ^"
            result ^= CDec(numbers(i))
    End Select
Next
MessageBox.Show(result)
```

That's my code, for example "1+4+2*3" how can i edit my code to start with the multiplication first and division then + and - . Does someone have an idea?

Comment: Use parentheses - `(2*3)+1+4`.  Note you'll have to figure out where best to use parantheses so you don't affect the outcome, but `(` and `)` have a higher precendence. [Operator Precedence in Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw84t893.aspx)

Comment: how can i add them in my code and start with them?

Answer (score 0):

I am adding [mXparser](http://mathparser.org/) math parser library, which is written in C#, but is CLS compliant - it can be easily used with VB. Please follow [mXparser Hello World tutorial for VB](http://mathparser.org/mxparser-hello-world/mxparser-hello-world-visual-basic/).

```
Dim e As Expression = New Expression("2+(3-sin(pi))")
mXparser.consolePrintln( e.calculate() )
```

Regards